# Re-assigning variable types/values in "strong" code languages

Tags: java, python, c, variables

I recently red a book about Python that went into a little detail on Python's ability to re-assign variable types (int, str, float, etc.) on the fly which is one of Python's strengths (as far as I am aware).

However, this is not the case in other programming languages, such as C and Java. From what I know, you must first declare the type of variable that the variable is, such as int or str and *then* assign its value.

Is there a way to re-assign that variable's type, say if you were to delete its value first?

Comment: Why would you ever do this instead of just using another variable?  One that reflects the different type and different meaning that variable is supposed to have?

Comment: Do note, @killhooligan, that there are good reasons why Python is written in C, and not the other way around.  For one thing, static data typing affords much greater opportunity for optimization of both computation and storage.

Comment: sure, use `Object` type for everything :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of value a C variable can hold is a fixed characteristic of that variable.  More generally, every expression in C has a data type that can be determined based on the containing program's source code alone.  C has mechanisms to convert *values* from one type to another, but that's a different beast.  (Also, "converting" a value should be understood as an operation that accepts an input value and produces a different output value, as opposed to modifying a single value in-place.  The same distinction applies to Python, too.)

C also supports data types ("unions") that provide overlapping storage for member values of different types.  Variables having such types can be considered able to contain values of different types at different times.  The particular types they can contain are specified in advance and cannot change, however.

In Python, on the other hand, data type is not a characteristic of variables, but it is still a characteristic of *values*.  Each Python value has a specific type that never changes, but you can replace the value of a variable with a value of a different type.

Answer (score 1):

C and Java are both strongly typed languages.  Once the type is defined, it doesn't change.  As a result the compiler is able to perform type checking in all expressions to ensure that the proper type is in use for the context it is in.

There are instances where you can use a type cast to switch between one type and another, but those are exceptions rather than the rule.

Comment: You mean "statically typed".